# Custom django inlineformset validation based on user permissions

Tags: python, django, validation, django-forms, inline-formset

The objective is to have a simple workflow where an order and associated orderlines (created in a previous step) needs to be approved by the relevant budget holder. The approval form shows all order lines but disables those lines that the current user is not associated with (they should be able to see the overall order but only be able to edit lines that they are permitted to). They should be able to add new lines if necessary. The user needs to decide whether to approve or not (approval radio cannot be blank)

[image]

The initial form presents correctly and is able to save inputs correctly when all values are inputted correctly - however, if it fails validation then the incorrect fields get highlighted and their values are cleared.

[image]

**models.py**

```
class Order(models.Model):
    department = models.ForeignKey(user_models.Department, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    location = models.ForeignKey(location_models.Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    project = models.ForeignKey(project_models.Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ManyToManyField(catalogue_models.Product, through='OrderLine', related_name='orderlines')
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description

class OrderLine(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project_line = models.ForeignKey(project_models.ProjectLine, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=False)
    product = models.ForeignKey(catalogue_models.Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=4)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    budgetholder_approved = models.BooleanField(null=True)

    def get_line_total(self):
        total = self.quantity * self.price
        return total

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.total = self.get_line_total()
        super(OrderLine, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.name
```

**views.py**

```
class BudgetApprovalView(FlowMixin, generic.UpdateView):
    form_class = forms.BudgetHolderApproval

    def get_object(self):
        return self.activation.process.order

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(BudgetApprovalView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        if self.request.POST:
            data['formset'] = forms.OrderLineFormet(self.request.POST, instance=self.object)
        else:
            data['formset'] = forms.OrderLineFormet(instance=self.activation.process.order, form_kwargs={'user': self.request.user})
        return data


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        self.object = None
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        form = forms.BudgetHolderApproval(self.request.POST, instance=self.activation.process.order)
        formset = forms.OrderLineFormet(self.request.POST, instance=self.activation.process.order)

        if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            return self.is_valid(form, formset)

        else:
            return self.is_invalid(form, formset)

    def is_valid(self, form, formset):

        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.created_by = self.request.user
        self.activation.process.order = self.object


        with transaction.atomic():
            self.object.save()
            self.activation.done()
            formset.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

    def is_invalid(self, form, formset):

        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form, formset=formset))
```

I have tried a couple of things to figure this out - without success:

1. to override the clean() method of the ModelForm - however, I cannot figure out how to determine if the submitted form is disabled or not.

**forms.py**

```
class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Order
        fields = ['description', 'project', 'location']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OrderForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_tag = False


class OrderLine(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.OrderLine
        exclude = ['viewflow']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        YES_OR_NO = (
            (True, 'Yes'),
            (False, 'No')
        )

        self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)

        super(OrderLine, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['project_line'].queryset = project_models.ProjectLine.objects.none()
        self.fields['budgetholder_approved'].widget = forms.RadioSelect(choices=YES_OR_NO)

        if self.instance.pk:
            self.fields['budgetholder_approved'].required = True
            self.fields['order'].disabled = True
            self.fields['project_line'].disabled = True
            self.fields['product'].disabled = True
            self.fields['quantity'].disabled = True
            self.fields['price'].disabled = True
            self.fields['total'].disabled = True
            self.fields['budgetholder_approved'].disabled = True

        if 'project' in self.data:
            try:
                project_id = int(self.data.get('project'))
                self.fields['project_line'].queryset = project_models.ProjectLine.objects.filter(project_id=project_id)
            except (ValueError, TypeError):
                pass
        elif self.instance.pk:
            self.fields['project_line'].queryset = self.instance.order.project.projectline_set
            project_line_id = int(self.instance.project_line.budget_holder.id)
            user_id = int(self.user.id)

            if project_line_id == user_id:
                self.fields['budgetholder_approved'].disabled = False


        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.template = 'crispy_forms/templates/bootstrap4/table_inline_formset.html'
        self.helper.form_tag = False

    def clean(self):

        super(OrderLine, self).clean()

        pprint(vars(self.instance))
        
        //This just returns a list of fields without any attributes to apply the validation logic


OrderLineFormet = forms.inlineformset_factory(
    parent_model=models.Order,
    model=models.OrderLine,
    form=OrderLine,
    extra=2,
    min_num=1
)
```

2. to override the clean() method of the BaseInlineFormSet - however, I cannot disable the fields in the **init**  or any of the validation rules (it silently fails validation and presents a blank inlineformset on failure - it never gets to clean() method.

**forms.py**

```
class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Order
        fields = ['description', 'project', 'location']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TestOrderForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_tag = False


class BaseTestOrderLine(forms.BaseInlineFormSet):
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = user

        super(BaseTestOrderLine, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.template = 'crispy_forms/templates/bootstrap4/table_inline_formset.html'
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        
    // Never gets to the clean method as is_valid fails silently

    def clean(self):
        super(BaseTestOrderLine, self).clean()

        if any(self.errors):

            pprint(vars(self.errors))

            return
            
OrderLineFormet = forms.inlineformset_factory(
    parent_model=models.Order,
    model=models.OrderLine,
    formset=BaseTestOrderLine,
    exclude=['order'],
    extra=2,
    min_num=1
)
```

**Edit** - reflecting progress based on Dao's suggestion (the form reloads correctly with the validation errors showing correctly)

The only remaining problem is that when the form reloads - the field (budgetholder_approved) that should still be enabled is disabled. One of the two approval checkbox lines lines should be editable

[image]

Comment: Interesting problem.  Just curious, how many lines in the formset will the user need to review?  Just wondering, because if it's only a few at a time, you could get all kinds of granular control and customization by looping a regular form class.  Downside is you may have to save each line individually.  Again, depends on the number.  For formsets in general though, if you want to do anything with a line, you need to treat it in a loop: `for form in formset: # do something`.

Comment: Hi Milo - thanks for the response. In terms of number of lines - it is dynamic (it depends on however many lines are entered in the original order. So it could be 10 or 500. As for your suggestion about looping the form in the formset - where would you put this code?

Comment: The view would need a function to generate a list of forms, each with its own object instance.  The template would unpack that.  Based on the number of objects your dealing with, I'm not sure I'd go that route.  Formsets are likely a good solution, along with custom validation.  As a first step, I'd consider adding `blank=True` and/or `null=True` to your model fields like 'quantity', 'product', etc.  That's why the form is saying "required" and not submitting.  Then handle what's required or not on the model form class.

Comment: By the way, do you have any ajax that refreshes the form and presents errors from validators?  I think this might be your primary missing piece if so.

Comment: Hi Milo - the validation is failing on the "budgetholder_approved" field where the model allows a null value. So the validation defined by the model should not fail (all the other fields for the existing lines are already present so these should not fail either). In any case - where I am trying to override the formset in the __init__ this should be defining the validation rules. I am avoiding ajax at this point as I am trying to have the validation on the backend before improving the UX

Answer (score 0):

Looks like because you have different formset context data on submit invalid

```
        if self.request.POST:
            data['formset'] = forms.OrderLineFormet(self.request.POST, instance=self.activation.process.order, form_kwargs={'user': self.request.user})
        else:
            data['formset'] = forms.OrderLineFormet(instance=self.activation.process.order, form_kwargs={'user': self.request.user})
        return data
```

**Edit for updated Q:**
Didn't test this out because  of time constraint but because you already initiated the field and overwrite the widget, so if you need to update `disabled` attr of widget instead of field.

```py
self.fields['budgetholder_approved'].widget = forms.RadioSelect(choices=YES_OR_NO)
self.fields['budgetholder_approved'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = False
```

Comment: Hi Dao - sorry am late in responding. I cannot recall why I did it this way. In the end I do not think this changes anything as the "self.object" will still return self.activation.process.order from the get_object(self) method. My understanding of the instance is that this is refering to the underlying record (in this case the Order) - not neccessarily the form instance. Would this change the behaviour?

Comment: I am an idiot! Your correction does help resolve the initial validation problem. There is one problem that remains. When the form with the validation reloads - the field that should be enabled (budgetholder_approved) is reloaded in a disabled state. I updated the question to illustrate